# Is GeoCouch compatible with heroku?

Tags: heroku, couchdb, geospatial

Is GeoCouch compatible with heroku?
If not...what could be an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

GeoCouch [requires a couchdb installation with source code](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/#prerequisites). Heroku has an add-on called [Cloudant](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudant), which claims to be couch-db compatible.

To find out if GeoCouch works you could try following the [GeoCouch installation instructions](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/#installation) to get, compile, and run GeoCouch with your database. It looks like you might have to create a [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), or commit the GeoCouch files to your git depo and copy them on deployment.